# Selenium Webdriver Handling Popup window

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am trying to Automate a login scenario of my project.
After Hitting the URL a POPUP Authentication window comes even before the page loads.
If we not pass that window we can't see the home page.

the problem is once the pop-up comes i can't inspect the element using firebug,its not letting me to click anywhere else.

i tries to handle the window but still the control is not going to the username and password text box.
 i tried windowhandle,robot class but not working.
Please anybody can help??

here is the piece of code:-

```
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
        System.out.println(handles.size());
        Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
        }
        driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler);
also the robot class:-

 Robot rb = new Robot();

                //Enter user name by ctrl-v
                StringSelection username = new StringSelection("myusername");
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(username, null);  
                Thread.sleep(2000);
river.switchTo().window(mainHandle);
                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
                    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
                    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_M);
                    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_M);
                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);


                //tab to password entry field
                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                Thread.sleep(2000);

                //Enter password by ctrl-v
                StringSelection pass = new StringSelection("password");
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(pass, null);
                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

                //press enter
                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

                //wait
                Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to automate the browser based authentication using Selenium.

- If your authentication is http based then try opening the url using format - `http://username:password@example.com/` instead of `example.com`.
- If at all you still want to automate it then use third party plugins like [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) to accomplish it which works along with Selenium. AutoIt is used to automate windows based desktop applications including browsers. Here are few links that you can refer to -

  - [Login to chrome using AutoIt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20592823/4180674)
  - [Handling Authentication using AutoIt](http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-in-selenium-webdriver)
  - [Use AutoIt with Selenium](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/autoit-selenium-webdriver/)
- Also you can use plugins for firefox which authenticates the popups automatically, when you open the url. But this is a manual setup and you have to perform authentication once so that the plugin remembers it. [Here's one of them](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autoauth/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Girish, the 1st option is not working i tried,before page loads that authentication pop-up comes.
2ndly how can we use AutoIT with Selenium Webdriver to automate that can u plzz describe.

Comment: That's a whole big process. Updated answer with few links that can help you with your automation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing. you can try it.

If we press ESC button then application stop processing many times.

after clicking on event use this below code:-

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
```

above code will press ESC for you. Now you can get the time to find the element.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Hi Shubham,
i am not able to inspect element on that authentication pop-up. it askes first to give input on that pop-up.