# Chrome 59 support for basic auth credentials in URLs alternative for usage with Chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pytest

With Chrome 59 the support for putting basic auth credentials in URLs - like `https://foo:bar@www.foo.com` has ended - this was warned a while ago within https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856.

Has anyone had to work around this with Selenium and Chromedriver yet? Specifically within Python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome 59 and Basic Authentication with Selenium/Fluentlenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44542740/chrome-59-and-basic-authentication-with-selenium-fluentlenium)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In our situation (automated testing using WebDriver via C# with NTLM auth) we found that once you hit the page with the credentials although you can't load the sub-resources on the page you are still authorized for that browser session.

So we go to a page that we don't want to test (in our case the home page) with valid credentials in order to get authorized at the start of our test suite. From then on we browse to the pages we want to test without any credentials and so long as we don't close the session everything works.