# Protractor/Selenium embedded credentials dropped support for chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, testing, protractor

I am currently managing a staging environment with some authentication.

I was able to run my tests by embedding credentials to URL like this:

https://johndoe:foobar@app.s.product.com/#login

However, my tests fail because of chrome, dropping this feature(https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856). Is there any other way I can access our staging site? I tried inspecting the popup for credentials and maybe I can sendKeys(), but to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome 59 and Basic Authentication with Selenium/Fluentlenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44542740/chrome-59-and-basic-authentication-with-selenium-fluentlenium)

Answer (score 2):

Have this problem too. My solution is creation chrome extension and add it to chrome on startup.

1. Create two files in some new folder:

*background.js* (change user and path with yourth)

```
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
        function(details, callbackFn) {
            console.log("onAuthRequired!", details, callbackFn);
            callbackFn({
                authCredentials: {username: "user", password: "pass"}
            });
        },
        {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
        ['asyncBlocking']
    );
```

*manifest.json*

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Authentication for tests",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "permissions": ["<all_urls>", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

2. Pack them into crx (chrome://extensions/ -> Pack extension)
3. Add this file to project
4. Add to conf.js:

As first line

```
var fs = require('fs');
const ext64 = fs.readFileSync('./ext.crx', 'base64');
exports.config = {
...
```

and to chrome options

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        args: ['--no-sandbox'],
        extensions: [ext64]
    }
},
```