# "No Alert Open" when trying to put login credentials before the website is opened completely

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, alert

[image]I am trying to access a website, However to access the website first I need to enter username and password, After that full website will get open. When I try to send username and password through "alert.sendkeys", it gives error "No alert open". Please note website will only open when you have put the username and password first and then click on "Sign In" for authorization.My browser is chrome, version:64 and chrome driver version is :2.38. Here is my code:

```
public static void launchWebsite(String URL) {
        driver.get(URL);
        try {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            System.out.println(alert.getText());
           alert.sendKeys("website");
           alert.sendKeys("grren");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("No alertis present");
            //exception handling
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - Basic Authentication via url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345882/selenium-basic-authentication-via-url)

Comment: @DebanjanB The link you provided did not helped me to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`driver.get("http://UserName:Password@Example.com");` should do the trick if the site uses basic authentication.

Special note: if you have @ in your password, don't forget to replace that bad boy by a `%40`

In case your authentication server requires username with domain like "domainuser" you need to add double slash / to the url:
`//localdomain\user:password@example.com`

EDIT:

Chrome 59 has removed support [for https://user:password@example.com URLs.](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856)

You can use the following method to handle it in **IE as of selenium 3.4**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);      
Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());     
alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(username, password));
```

There is way of handling this [using Chrome extension](https://gist.github.com/florentbr/25246cd9337cebc07e2bbb0b9bf0de46). More [explanation can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44679605/5074293)

OR

Downgrade your chrome version to <59

Comment: Ok tried that but than I am getting error- This site can’t be reached
https’s server IP address could not be found.

Comment: Here is my code-String URL = "http://" + uname + ":" + pwd + "@" + TEST_ENVIRONMENT;  (I have passed username to "uname" and password to "pwd" and put the website url in :TEST_ENVIRONMENT:)

Comment: I also tried this: "http://uname:pwd@www.staging-barneys.com/";.......but it says cannot navigate to invalid URL

Comment: Did you try `https://uname:pass@staging.barneys.com`? I see that you used `http` instead of `https`

Comment: Yea i tried that still didn't opened that.I put in the correct URL, don't why it is still saying that it is invalid URL

Comment: please update the question with the browser, browser version, driver version, updated url variable

Comment: Ok done that, I didn't understand what do you mean by updated URL variable?

Comment: Edited my answer