# how to login to the alert window when we navigate to the browser through selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the url which needs credentials and I am navigating to that through selenium + Java
https://username:password.example.com/

However it still shows the login window but not as an alert window. Attached the screenshot. I tried the below code but it did not work

```
 UserAndPassword UP = new UserAndPassword("username","password");
 driver.switchTo().alert().authenticateUsing(UP);
```

Is there anyway I can do it?[image: the page with login window]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome 59 and Basic Authentication with Selenium/Fluentlenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44542740/chrome-59-and-basic-authentication-with-selenium-fluentlenium)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing @ symbol after user name and password. You can try like below,

https://username:password@test.discoverykidsplay.com/

Comment: As mentioned above by @Florent B, this feature has been removed from Chrome.

Comment: sorry though I mentioned wrongly here but I have used @ correctly. https://username:password@test.discoverykidsplay.com/ this gives some weird css problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44720113/css-distortion-while-url-gets-opened-in-chrome-through-selenium)So I thought I would try the below one (i.e http://username:password@es.testserver.test.dkids.mercury.dnitv.com/) which if i directly put in the browser manually it resolves and redirects to test.discoverykdisplay.com but if i go through selenium it shows me the login window though url gets resolved to test.discoverykidsplay.com

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.codemiller.com/blog/2011/05/28/overcoming-auth-pop-ups/) provides multiple approaches for handling Authentication pop-ups.

I would suggest to 
use WebDriver’s `switchTo.alert()` syntax to access them and then use methods such as `sendKeys()`, `accept()` or `dismiss()`