# need to signin to the signin prompt after giving url in chrome using python script

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

How to handle the login pop up window using Selenium Webdriver? I have attached the sample screen here. How can I enter/input Username and Password to this login pop up/alert window?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to login to the alert window when we navigate to the browser through selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44722353/how-to-login-to-the-alert-window-when-we-navigate-to-the-browser-through-seleniu)