# robot framework test user role single sign-on

Tags: phantomjs, robotframework, uitest

I'm trying to use robot framework as a ui test tooling for a website we use internal.

To test different user roles I open the browser with basic authentication (http://user:ww@url). Unfortunately this methode is removed from chrome and chromedriver (http://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856) (for the test I use PhantomJS).
because of this issue subresource requests are blocked. See image attached.

[image]

Because of this issue also js files are blocked and therefore my UI tests don't work properly.

Does anybody have an idee on how to solve this or another way of testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is being encountered by all browser automation frameworks. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44588777/6152737) describes an approach to take a two step approach:

1. Go to the url with http://user:pass@hostname.ext
2. Go to the url with http://hostname.ext

The username and password are cached and subsequent visits will reuse it.

Comment: this, including running VS as admin :)