# Entering basic auth popup info with python and chrome > 59

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

I'm trying to set up a proxy with basic auth for chromedriver, I have a working squid proxy set up on an EC2 node. I found the following code (slightly modified)

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=options)

    driver.get("https://yahoo.com")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    alert = wait.until(EC.alert_is_present())
    alert = driver.switch_to(alert)
    alert.send_keys('myname')
    alert.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
    alert.send_keys('mypass')
    alert.accept()
```

However The auth Box is not being filled. How can I get this working?

Edit, this is not a duplicate question. I am using chrome 64, and chromedriver. not firefox. I'm also using a proxy (not in the other question) I tried the accepted answer which did not work. Apparently anything above chrome 59 will not allow this method ([Chrome 59 and Basic Authentication with Selenium/Fluentlenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44542740/chrome-59-and-basic-authentication-with-selenium-fluentlenium)) .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Windows Authentication username and password is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328654/python-windows-authentication-username-and-password-is-not-working)

Comment: Please see edit

Comment: What do you mean specifically by "The auth Box"? The Username? Password? Both?

Comment: I'm talking about the popup box you see for basic auth - see screenshot

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is building the url as:

```
http://username:password@url
```