# How can i download image using selenium webdriver by right clicking the image in java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to save the image by right clicking using selenium and also by "Authenticating the browser with username and password". the link which i am sending through selenium looks like this  "http://111.111.2.125/capture".

As I am new this concept, any suggestions will be highly helpful.

Comment: Your question header is about `download image`where as description mentions about `Authenticating the browser with username and password`. Can you consider showcasing your work please? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB After loading my link there will be popup foe authentication , after authentication i need to download the image ?

Comment: For that you need to write some code. Did you try out anything? Can you consider showcasing your work please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**For Right Click on Image you can use :**

```
WebElement Image =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@border='0']")); 
Actions action= new Actions(driver); 
action.contextClick(Image).build().perform();
```

**Select "Save Image As" option**

If you see In Image, We can select "Save Image As" option using CONTROL + V from keyboard. To do It In selenium webdriver, We will use bellow given code.

```
action.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, "v").build().perform();
```

Comment: Can you please tell how can i authenticate the webbrowser with username and password when the link is loaded?

Comment: @nodemail Are you getting popup when link is loaded?

Comment: Yes i am getting the popup for authentication using username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Hope answer by @sForSujit has helped you for 'Right Clicking' on the image.

For Authenticating the browser with username and password, You could consider passing credentials in URL
First, visit the URL with credentials then visit the URL without credentials

Example:
First, access

http://username:password@111.111.2.125/capture

Then, access below one-

http://111.111.2.125/capture

Comment: Starting Chrome v-59, this has been disabled. Please see the detailed discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44443375/google-59-no-longer-supports-embedded-credentials/44767023#44767023). Actual Chromium announcement is [here](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856).

Comment: @demouser123 - Thank you for updating me on this.