# AutoIT Script to Handle Chrome Authentication Window

Tags: google-chrome, autoit

I have the following script based on the following link: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357634/seleniumautoit-script-to-handle-windows-authentication-pop-up-on-chrome)

```
If(Not IsArray($CmdLine) Or $CmdLine[0] < 2) Then
$user = InputBox ("User", "Please enter your user", "")
$pass = InputBox ("Password", "Please enter your password", "", "*M")
Else
$user = $CmdLine[1]
$pass = $CmdLine[2]
EndIf

WinWaitActive("", "Authentication Required", "120")
If WinExists("", "Authentication Required") Then
Send($user)
Send("{TAB}")
Send($pass)
Send("{ENTER}")
EndIf
```

This is not working for me, nothing is getting entered into the User name and password field when I run a test with this. I even created a script where I was simply sending a string to the user name and password fields and it is not working either.

Comment: You wait until the window is active, then you check if it exists?  What happens if you remove the `WinExists` check?

Comment: @Mr.Llama The same behavior. Absolutely nothing is happening.

Comment: Is it ever making it past the `WinWaitActive` command?  Try adding a `MsgBox` command afterwards to verify that it is.  Be sure to check `WinWaitActive`'s return value to verify that it wasn't from a timeout.

Comment: I added a message box box right after the `WinWaitActive` command and that doesnt show up either

Comment: There ya go then.  AutoIt isn't seeing the authentication window.  I just checked Chrome 40 on Windows 7 and it appears that the login prompt has the text `Chrome Legacy Window`, not `Authentication Required`.  You should consult with the "AutoIt Window Info" tool that comes standard with AutoIt.  It's quite handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This was solved in the comments but I'm copying the answer here for future readers.)

It appears that the `WinWaitActive` command is never finding the login prompt that you're looking for.  On Chrome 40 on Windows 7, the login prompt's only visible text is `Chrome Legacy Window`, not `Authentication Required` (which is what you're looking for).

I would recommend checking with the "AutoIt Window Info" tool that comes standard with AutoIt.  Open a Chrome authentication box, freeze the Window Info tool, then check the "Visible Text" tab.